# SoftLayer Rest API attachDiskImage call throwing error

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying with the below one it always throws "You must provide a valid portable storage volume id.". I have replaced my virtualGuestId,imageId,user name and apikey in below curl.

```
curl "https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/attachDiskImage.json?imageId=[imageId]"
```

Please let me know the correct API to use to load an disk image and how to fetch the details of disk image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you to take a look at these links:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/more-softlayer-rest-api-examples
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST

Well the method attachDiskImage has as parameters the "imageId" of the portable storage as you can see in documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/attachDiskImage

The parameters must be sent using the POST method and you need to send those parameters in a payload with a JSON format, so your request should be changed to this one:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"parameters":[$IMAGEID]}' https://$SLUSERNAME:$SLAPIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VIRTUALGUESTID/attachDiskImage.json

Note: replace $IMAGEID, $SLUSERNAME, $SLAPIKEY and $VIRTUALGUESTID
```

Regards

Comment: I have diskImageId/id which I got from 'getValidBlockDeviceTemplateGroups' and also tried with id which I got from '/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualDiskImages'. Both of these don't work. I am getting 'The requested disk is not a portable storage volume.' message.

Comment: those are not portable storages, in order to list all your portable storages you need to use this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes